# How to reconcile diffraction with the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle?

Tags: particle-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, diffraction, wave-particle-duality

When a particle of momentum $p$ (say $10^{-23}$ kg m/s e.g. an electron moving at 10 000 km/s) falls on a slit and passes through, what is its momentum after the slit? (One can also have a flux of such electrons, meaning that they are described by a plane wave and are not a wavepacket, so that the speed is more or less around 10 000 km/s) According to HUP $p_x$ must be between 0 and $p_x=h/dx$. For a very narrow slit with $dx=10^{-10}$ m, $p_x$ would be about $10^{-24}$ kg m/s. This means that the path is practically not altered. But after a slit the diffraction must change the paths so that they diverge in every direction. Which means that $p_x$ must be equal to $p$, in some cases. The difference is 10 times. Do some electrons of this speed diverge on 90* (or do they all follow a straight path)? If they diverge more does this brake HUP when $p>h/dx$?

Comment: $p=mv$, not $p=ev$.

Comment: Ah you mean p= 10^-30. Oh I took charge 10^-19. Nevertheless if speed is 10000 km/sec  then p=10^-23 and can be 10 times greater than HUP limit.

Comment: The problem has been studied for light. Note that in space even the constant speed c projects to a Δp and Δx. see for example the summary     https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4775.pdf

Comment: @annav interesting that this seems not to have been published in a peer reviewed journal.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero maybe because it is just like a good classroom experiment? They wanted to make it available but not worth for publishing?  The same with all those single particle double slit that are just in curious byways.